# Is a full html page needed when loading a page with jQuery mobile?

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am currently looking at jQuery mobile and its system of loading web pages with XmlHttpRequest. Thanks to that it is possible to automatically perform transition animations between two pages, for instance.

However, something is not clear to me. If I understand correctly, each new page of a jQuery mobile powered website is injected in the DOM of the initial web page. The documentation of jQuery mobile even tells that because of this mechanism, the `<title>` tag of new webpages are not taken into account.

So, in a way, if my initial webpage A.html loads a page B.html, I would tend to think that the webpage B.html does not need to have a full HTML grammar with the `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

My page B.html could directly begin with a `<div>` element.

Am I right?
Is a full html page needed when loading a HTML page with jQuery mobile?
What are the pros and cons about having a webpage with a wrong/truncated HTML syntax (appart that this page should not be accessed directly but through the main page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But then what happens when a user starts off on `A.html`, then goes to `B.html`, and then refreshes the page? jQuery Mobile uses a `pushState` plugin that updates the URL as if the user had gone to the `B.html` page normally. This means that if the user refreshes on `B.html`, there won't be the proper includes to create your mobile site if it's not a full document.

My recommendation is to include the jQuery Mobile JS/CSS files in each document, to include the jQuery Core JS file in each document, and to include external custom JS/CSS files that holds all the necessary JS and CSS for your site. This way no matter what page in your site the user accesses, it will include all the necessary information. This doesn't add a whole lot of bloat to your site, just a few lines of includes per page. Most of the time all of those includes will be ignored when jQuery Mobile pulls a page into the DOM via AJAX (jQuery Mobile only grabs the first `data-role="page"` element and it's contents, everything else in the document is ignored).

**Long Story Short:**

The performance benefit to omitting a proper HTML structure to each document is not worth possibly breaking your user's experience for common occurrences such as refreshing a page (which happens automatically on many devices when a user opens the browser to an already open page).

A major **con** for not using a valid HTML structure is that you're hurting your SEO. The meta tags in the `<head>` of the documents should still be unique to the content in the page, so that search engine crawlers can properly index your site.

Comment: Hey i just updated my answer to include some stuff about SEO as an afterthought, before I saw your answer. Glad to see that were are on the same page and looking out for fellow stackoverflowers, so +1 my friend.

Comment: You are completely right about the "refresh" problem. I was thinking in the context of making a mobile application with WebView (on Android), so I forgot about this problem in the case of classical web pages. Moreover, good point about SEO.

Answer (score 2):

You "should" use a full page when using jQuery mobile, but it can of course get quite long and then it takes a long time to load everything in to the DOM. A lot of developers do not like this.

To answer your question: As long as you have a single, valid html page (the main page of your jquery mobile app), it can load a "wrong/trumcated" html file just fine. It can also load a properly formed html file just fine. It is up to you to go with whichever you feel looks cleaner.

Here is a similar q&a that helps support my point: [jQuery mobile multiple HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097905/jquery-mobile-multiple-html-files)

**A caveat:** If this is for a website that will be available online, and if you go with the approach of having multiple (and fragmented) pages, you may want to stop and think about SEO.. You will probably want a robots file to prevent Google bots from crawling the additional pages. If you are at all concerned with SEO on your entire site, then you should check out this article Google made on [Responsive web design for mobile](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2012/06/recommendations-for-building-smartphone.html). It could change your whole perspective right from the start.

My opinion is that you should have your jQuery Mobile site all on one page. You can always use JavaScript/jQuery to inject additional markup as you need it. That is the approach that I take for jQuery Mobile websites. On the other hand, if you are wrapping this in PhoneGap to be deployed as a native mobile app, then I would use the fragmented pages because, a) SEO would not apply to it, and b) I want the DOM to load as fast as possible so that it appears to load like a "true native app". I believe that fragmented pages would help it to load faster, and I know that injecting code with JavaScript/jQuery as you need it makes it load faster.

Comment: How does adding `<body>` and `<head>` tags make the page `quite long`? It adds an insignificant amount of overhead that will not make the load time any perceivable amount longer.

Comment: I mean to say that the content within the `<body>` tag can get extremely long. Every tutorial online uses a single page which is okay if there is not a lot of content, but in a real-world project that single page has to all load in to the DOM and can be quite large. One thing you do want to be careful of is building SEO up on fragmented pages.. so I am going to update my  answer based on that thought.

Comment: +1 because of the case of PhoneGap. Actually, my application is exactly to test PhoneGap. But I wondered about more generic scenarios using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @Jasper brings up a really good point about pushState and page refreshes if you have separate pages, but that applies to jQuery mobile as a website. When using PhoneGap you would be safe to have separate pages because the user does not have control over the browser, and you can use PhoneGap to handle events such as the user pressing the "back" button on their Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load an external html file, it is probably better to have a fully formed html page. That html page should also have `<div data-role="page">` tag. I think jquery mobile will look for that tag and load the new page based on that.

You can also include the html for all your pages into one page say "A.html". each page html should start with `<div data-role="page">`

Comment: Could you provide a source for the `I think...` statement?